# Change href file but not query string with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like users with [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) enabled to see page results.php.
Users with JavaScript disabled should see results_d.php.

To do this I'm initially displaying my links with results_d.php.
Then by using JavaScript to change the destination in the links, only the users with JavaScript enabled will see the rich content.

There are a few questions on here about using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to change the whole href destination, but how can I just change the file name and keep the query string as it is?

I was thinking something like this, but it's not working...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a').attr('href').replace('results_d', 'results');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('a').attr('href', function(index, href) {
        return 'results?'+(href.split('?')[1])
    });
});
```

Comment: works for me.. a problem could be, that the selector is somewhat generic. Maybe it would help if you would a class to those links, that you want to change and then call `$("a.your_class").attr(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('results_d', 'results'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but they don't seem to work for me.

Here is one of my links...

[code]
<a href="/search/results_d.php?kwds=whatever&amp;search_mode=abc&amp;countries[]=ALL" class="medtxt">View all results</a>
[/code]

Comment: $(this).attr("href") is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replied guys. I got a few errors with that logic though in my file. I've added my errors to the comments.

In the end, what did work for me was:

```
$('a').each(function()
{ 
    this.href = this.href.replace('results_d', 'results');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function(){
  
  jQuery("a").each(function(e,i){
    
    jQuery(this).attr("href",i.href.replace("results_d","results"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/search/results_d.php?kwds=whatever&amp;search_mode=abc&amp;countries[]=AL‌​L" class="medtxt">View all results</a> 
<a href="/search/results_d.php?asd=whatever&amp;search_mode=abc&amp;countries[]=AL‌​L" class="medtxt">View all results</a> 
<a href="/search/results_d.php?kwdfgds=whatever&amp;search_mode=abc&amp;countries[]=AL‌​L" class="medtxt">View all results</a>
```

I know this is kinda late, but I wasn't on stackoverflow in 2010 and I couldn't resist to answer this unanswered question.

Thanks!!

Comment: Aww!! I just saw that you had already given the answer in javascript. Kindly ignore!!